# where to find sitekey in flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, firebase

i was trying to convert my app into web, and then there is a problem here

```
 captcha__en.js:262 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey
 at Ic.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:262:153)
 at new Ic (recaptcha__en.js:674:508)
 at zU.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:81:254)
 at new zU (recaptcha__en.js:560:510)
 at recaptcha__en.js:268:45
 at recaptcha.ts:150:35
 at recaptcha.ts:105:3
```

here is my index.html code

```
<body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
    self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
</script>
<script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyAicjjbZS62Lj4yOU9gTTjU1Aw9OUJ2bE8",
        authDomain: "rekammedis-b4f1a.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://rekammedis-b4f1a-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
        projectId: "rekammedis-b4f1a",
        storageBucket: "rekammedis-b4f1a.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "970959788928",
        appId: "1:970959788928:web:545de091cbe2c434d63f65",
        measurementId: "G-RFFJ52BX2Y",
        sitekey: "7782F8C6-C0F2-41A0-B006-F7C100EF63FE",
      };


      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

anyone know how to solve this ?
I have trying to read the documentation, but i still didnt get it

Comment: Please Check if Firebase is initialized in main.dart? Flutter compiler would read the main.dart before  the index.html file.